# Elusive Badge Weirdness

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

The answers to this question [For those that demand those elusive badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/for-those-that-demand-those-elusive-badges) display normally when I'm not logged in.  But when I log in I see a lot of "alt text".

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I believe the server they were using for badges is down: http://uvshock.co.uk/badge.php?label=I%20Am%20Awesome&medal=gold is a direct link given in one of the badges

Comment: @Earlz - Just tried again.  It really seems to be a difference between being logged in and not logged in.  I'll look into it, I just though maybe someone else had seen this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

The answers are displayed in a different order when logged in/out, so I wasn't comparing the same answers.

Sorry for the trouble.